# Passing a struct to void* param then copying it to a void*, reconstructing gives garbage value

Tags: c

I am really confused with passing my struct to void pointers, I'm not sure which one can be assigned directly and which one should be `memcpy`ed, I've tried a lot of combinations but it does not seem to work. Any help would be very appreciated!

This is my C code

```
struct SomeStruct {
  int a;
  char name[10];
};

void *randoms[10];

void transferFunction(void* data, int index) {
    // This function copies data to randoms[index]
    // I would like to have the whole struct's data in randoms[index]
    memcpy(&randoms[index], data, sizeof(struct SomeStruct));
}        

struct SomeStruct *ss = malloc(sizeof(struct SomeStruct)); 
ss->a = 1;
strcpy(ss->name, "abc");
transferFunction(ss, 0);
```

My goal is to have the randoms[index] having the struct's data as another function is going to read from it, as shown below, but I am unable to retrieve the struct data correctly, it gives me some garbage value

```
void readFunction() {
     struct *SomeStruct ss = malloc(sizeof(struct SomeStruct)); 
     memcpy(ss, &randoms[index], sizeof(struct SomeStruct));
     printf(ss->name);
}
```

Does anyone knows how to solve this problem? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: You called "transferFuncion(ss)", but you haven't set the index param. You should call "transferFunction(ss, 0)

Comment: The statements like `ss->a` at top level make no sense.

Comment: `struct *SomeStruct` makes no sense .  you mean `struct SomeStruct *`.

Comment: `&randoms[index]` has type `void**` and points at an object of type `void*`. That `void*` object might not have enough bytes for a `memcpy` of `sizeof(struct SomeStruct)` bytes to write into without overlapping other elements of `randoms`.

Comment: I see. Is there a workaround to still make the randoms[index] as the destination buffer? @aschepler

Comment: There's a design issue to figure out. What kind / where is the memory that should hold the `SomeStruct` objects long-term? If it's directly in the array, that would be `struct SomeStruct randoms[10];` and not much `void*` is involved. Maybe `transferFunction` calls `malloc` to get memory that will be valid long enough - see the answer by LevM - but then there's the question of when and how it will get `free`-d. Or maybe the caller of `transferFunction` needs to guarantee the pointer passed in will be valid as long as needed, in which case `transferFunction` is just `{ randoms[index] = data; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not "copy in to a void".

A `void *` can contain a memory address, but does not contain any information about the size of the data at that address.

Also, it can not contain any data, only an address!

In this line:

```
void *randoms[10];
```

You create an array that can hold 10 addresses.

You never initialize this array, so it will start out all zeroes (this only works for global variables in C).

You can put the address of your structure in to the array, like so:

```
random[0] = (void*)ss;
```

However, this does not transfer any data, so if you `free` the original structure (`ss`) your data is gone, and the address in `random[0]` is illegal.

If you want to transfer data you need to create array of `struct SomeStruct` or you need to allocate another `SomeStruct`, store its address in `random[0]` then `memcpy` to that address.

```
void transferFunction(void* data, int size, int index)
{
    randoms[index] = malloc(size);
    if (randoms[index] != NULL) {
        memcpy(randoms[index], data, size);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some problems:

- `struct *SomeStruct ss = ...` should be `struct SomeStruct *ss =`.
- You are not cheking the return value of `malloc()` (which may fail).
- You are not freeing `ss` allocated with `malloc()`. You should call `free()` on `ss`.

> My goal is to have the randoms[index] having the struct's data

[Lev M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10302746/lev-m)'s answer already answers this part.

> as another function is going to read from it

Simply assign your void pointer to a `SomeStruct` pointer:

```c
void readFunction(int index)
{
    if (index >= 10) // Index out of range
        return;
    
    struct SomeStruct *ss = randoms[index];
    printf("%s\n", ss->name);
}
```

Comment: Hi Zakk, thanks for the answer! Sorry I was unclear about the problem that I am facing, I'm not receiving a segfault but I am unable to retrieve the content of my struct back, as i need to read it from readFunction. Do you have any idea why? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are missing one more thing `&randoms[index]` this is not a memory address you can `memcpy` to, look at how `randoms` is declared.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! How do I make `&randoms[index]` be a destination buffer for this?